# What does "main method" and "helper method" in a recursion mean?

Tags: recursion

I got this assignment:

```
private int hex2Dec(String string) // helper method
private int hex2Dec(String string, int low, int high) // main method
```

It means the recursive method should look like this:

```
private int hex2Dec(String string, int low, int high) {
    ... some code ....
    hex2Dec(string);
}

private int hex2Dec(String string)
```

OR it means the recursive method should look like this:

```
private int hex2Dec(String string) {
    ... some code ....
    hex2Dec(string, 0, string.length()-1);
}

private int hex2Dec(String string, int low, int high)
```

**What does "main method" and "helper method" means in recursion?**

In Daniel Liang's book "Introduction to Java Programming and Data Structures" 11th Global edition, on page 751 (chapter 18) he describes the helper method as a second method that receives additional parameters.

But in this assignment it's the one with less parameters called "helper method". And this confused me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those aren't recursion-specific terms.

In this case though, the "main function" is likely where they expect the actual recursion to happen.

And helpers functions are often used by recursive functions to simplify the initial calling. Often, as is the case here, the recursive calls require extra information (like `low` and `high`) to operate, but you don't want the user to need to worry about passing in starting values themselves. It's common to have the helper function call the recursive function with initial values for the extra parameters.

So in this case here, they likely want the helper to call the recursive function with values for `low` and `high`, and then the user can call the simpler helper instead of the resursive function.

Comment: This is exactly what's confusing: In Daniel Liang's book "Introduction to Java Programming and Data Structures" 11th Global edition, on page 751 (chapter 18) he describes the helper method as a second method that receives additional parameters. But in this taks he described the one with less parameters as helper method.

Comment: @Coder88 It's certainly possible to consider the recursive function the helper too. The main point is that complex recursive functions, for neatness and ease of use, often make use of secondary functions to offload some work to. Which function you consider to be the helper though is depends on perspective and what exactly each is doing. If they want the simpler function to be considered the helper in this case, then go with it.

Comment: @Coder88 If he explicitly states that the helper is the one that takes more arguments, then contradicts that in code though, that's probably just a typo.